# How to remove segmentedcontroller from uinavigationcontroller after view pops?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm building a segmented control within my viewDidLoad method, like so:

```
NSArray *tabitems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ONE", @"TWO", nil];
UISegmentedControl *tabs = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:tabitems];
tabs.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
tabs.frame = CGRectMake(185.0, 7.0, 130.0, 30.0);
tabs.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tabs];
[tabs release];
```

But when the user goes Back in the uinavigationcontroller hierarchy, the segmented controller stays on the navigation bar. How would I get rid of it? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

---

EDIT

Following Alex's suggestions, I propertized tabs and tried:

```
  NSArray *tabItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FAQs", @"Terms", nil];
  self.tabs = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:tabItems];
```

but I'm not sure it's a good idea to alloc a property;

And I'm using

```
  [self.tabs removeFromSuperview];
```

in my viewWillDisappear. Is that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retain a reference to the segmented control in your view controller (i.e define `tabs` as a property in the view controller's header file).

Override the view controller's [`-viewWillDisappear:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:) method, and remove the segmented control from the navigation bar there, using the control's [`-removeFromSuperview`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCBEIDB) method.

**EDIT**

You would still `alloc-init` your segmented control `tabs` in `-viewDidLoad`. You just need to set up a retain property for `tabs` in your view controller's header, and move the control's `release` statement to the view controller's `dealloc` method.

Read the "Properties" section of this [Objective-C tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) for an introduction to properties and how to set them up.

The way to override a method is as follows:

```
- (ReturnClass) methodNameToOverride:args {
    [super methodNameToOverride:args];
    // your code goes here...
}
```

In the case of `-viewWillDisappear:`, this method gets called when your view controller is about to disappear, such as when it gets popped off the navigation stack. This is a great place to put code that manages clean-up of view-controller-specific items, like your segmented control:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [tabs removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If your property is set as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *tabs;
```

then you are going to `retain` anything you set `self.tabs` equal to.

Your code here:

```
self.tabs = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:...];
```

will create a memory leak, because you are retaining this object: `[[UISegmentedControl alloc] init]` — but you never release `[[UISegmentedControl alloc] init]` itself. This is bad.

Instead, use `autorelease` on the right side, i.e.:

```
self.tabs = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:...] autorelease];
```

The `tabs` property retains its own reference to the initialized segmented control. That initialized segmented control is itself released properly at some later point. So no more memory leak.

Comment: Thanks. how would I set up the segmented control without alloc/init-ing it? And can you give me the line of code required in the viewWillDisappear method. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for 'Edit 2'. I had everything in place except the autorelease thing.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, set the UISegmentedControl's owning UIViewController's navigationItem.titleView to the UISegmentedControl.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    if(!mySegmentedControl) {
        // initialize the UISegmentedControl
        ...
    }

    self.navigationItem.titleView = mySegmentedControl; 
}
```

No manual removal of the UISegmentedControl or any other UIView for that matter required except, of course, releasing when owning UIViewController is dealloc'ed. Also, to be a "good memory citizen", you might set your property to nil in `-viewDidUnload`.

You can also customize the left and right barButtonItems of the UIViewController's navgiationItem.